# How to remove "." and ".." files from remote directory with C# and WinSCP

Tags: c#, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to get the files count from a remote directory using a SFTP connection, but I'm getting `.` and `..` and these are counted these dots like a files, I have 2 files in the remote directory but is counting 4 files including `.` and `..`.

Someone can help me how to solve this?

This is my code:

```
filesCount = session.ListDirectory(DataFile.sRemoteDirectory).Files.Count;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the WinSCP documentation](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory):

> You can use [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles) method instead, if you want to:
>
> - List only files matching a wildcard;
> - List the files recursively;
> - **Have references to this (.) and parent (..) directories be excluded form the listing.**

So it appears that you should change your code to do something more like this:

```
filesCount = 0; 
filesCount = session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(DataFile.sRemoteDirectory).Files.Count();                
session.Close();
```

Comment: I tried that option, for some reason EnumerateRemoteFiles is not displayed when I do it Session.

Comment: @JavierSalas Did you use uppercase or lowercase "session"?

Comment: `EnumerateRemoteFiles` is not available in the current stable release yet. + It returns `IEnumerable<RemoteFileInfo>`, so you need to call `.Count()` on the return value, not `.Files.Count`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `ListDirectory` you can use `EnumerateRemoteFiles` and it wont include ".." and "."

"." and ".." mean this directory and parent directory respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The `.` and `..` are references to this and parent directories respectively on most file systems.

---

To filter them, you can use new properties `.IsThisDirectory` and `.IsParentDirectory` of the [`RemoteFileInfo` class](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotefileinfo):

```
filesCount =   
    session.ListDirectory(DataFile.sRemoteDirectory).Files
        .Where(file => !file.IsThisDirectory && !file.IsParentDirectory).Count();
```

Note that you have to use the [`Enumerable.Count()` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count#system-linq-enumerable-count-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))), instead of the [`ICollection.Count` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.count) as the result of the `Enumerable.Where()` is the `IEnumerable`, not the `Collection` anymore.

---

Or to make it even easier, use the [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles()` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles), which with the `EnumerationOptions.None` option is functionally equivalent to the [`Session.ListDirectory()`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory), just that it excludes the `.` and `..`.

```
filesCount =
    session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
        DataFile.sRemoteDirectory, null, EnumerationOptions.None).Count();
```

---

If you want to filter all directories, use:

```
filesCount =   
    session.ListDirectory(DataFile.sRemoteDirectory).Files
        .Where(file => !file.IsDirectory).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try session.EnumerateRemoteFiles instead.

Answer (score 0):

Despite its naming, `Files` collection contains not only files, but all directory entries, including current and parent directory references.

If you want to count only files, filter them by `IsDirectory` property:

```
var filesCount = session.ListDirectory(dir).Files.Where(x => !x.IsDirectory).Count();
```

There's also `IsParentDirectory` and `IsThisDirectory` properties in the latest versions to filter ".." and "." cases without name comparison.

Comment: This excludes all directories, not just `.` and `..`. So while it works, if there are no other directories, it does not do exactly what the the question is asking for.